# How do I left pad a database column in FrontBase?

Tags: sql, frontbase

I have a table of items (let's call it `WIDGET`) that each have their own eight-digit barcode numbers stored in a VARCHAR field (let's call it `BARCODE`; the table's primary key is in a separate integer column `ID`). My problem is that some rows include the leading zeros, while others do not. I would like to **update all the existing records (several hundred in all) to eight digits** for the sake of consistency.

- `1` → `00000001`
- `234` → `00000234`
- `5678` → `00005678`
- `00009012` → `00009012`

I know FrontBase is SQL-92 compliant, but SQL-92 has no function specifically for left-padding strings. I already came up with a solution, but I am posting this question to see if anyone can think of a better way of doing this than I did.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (at least in FrontBase 5.2.9):

```
UPDATE WIDGET SET BARCODE =
SUBSTRING('00000000' || BARCODE FROM CHAR_LENGTH(BARCODE) + 1);
```